# Fetch data from Amazon dynamo db table using c#

Tags: c#, amazon-dynamodb

I have a created a dynamodb database table as;
ID | LineID | LineColor | LineWidth
1     1         red           2
2     1         blue          3
3     1         ornge         2
4     2         red           2

Id is the Hash key in my table. I need to fetch all the records having LineID = 1.

Can anyone help me out in getting this.

Thanks 
Vijay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using the Java SDK, however by following [the example](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/QueryScanORMModelExample.html) here:

```
 IEnumerable<Line> linesWithIdEqualToOne = context.Scan<Line>(
                new ScanCondition("LineID", ScanOperator.Equal, 1)
 );
```

should do the trick.

Edit: `Scan` goes over all the records and fetch only those that satisfies the `ScanCondition`.

You can also use [ScanRequest](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/latest/apidocs/items/T_Amazon_DynamoDBv2_Model_ScanRequest_NET4_5.html) if you don't want to use ORM.